# Dafny insufficient reads clause to read array element

Tags: arrays, dafny

```
datatype MSG_CMD = Empty| ReqS| ReqE| Inv| InvAck| GntS| GntE
type NODE=nat
type DATA=nat
type boolean=bool
class  class_0  {
var 
Data : DATA,
Cmd : MSG_CMD
}

class  class_1  {
var 
Data : DATA,
State : CACHE_STATE
}
class TopC{
var Cache : array<class_1 > }

predicate  inv__1(top:TopC,N1:nat,p__Inv0:nat, p__Inv2:nat)
  reads top
  reads top.Cache[p__Inv0]
  eads top.Cache[p__Inv2]
  requires top.Cache.Length ==N1
  requires N1>0
  requires top.Cache.Length ==N1
  requires N1>0
  requires 0<= p__Inv0<N1
  requires 0<= p__Inv2<N1
  {
(!((top.Cache[p__Inv2].State == E) && (!(top.Cache[p__Inv0].State == I))))
}
```

This is my test code,when i compile it ,find the error:insufficient reads clause to read array element on the line "reads top.Cache[p__Inv0]" ,I don't understand where i do wrong,is the reads annotation can not be used in the array's item?

Answer (score 0):

A function (including a predicate, which is a function that returns a `bool`) must declare the objects on whose state it depends. Predicate `inv__1` depends on

- the state of object `top`, because the function uses the `.Cache` field of that object
- the state of array `top.Cache`, because the function uses the elements of that array
- the state of the objects `top.Cache[p__Inv2]` and `top.Cache[p__Inv0]`, because the function uses the `.State` field of those objects

So, the function needs the following read frame:

```
reads top
reads top.Cache
reads top.Cache[p__Inv0], top.Cache[p__Inv2]
```

It's the second one of these that your program is missing.

If you never intend to change the `Cache` array itself, you can declare it as constant-after-construction:

```
const Cache: array<class_1>
```

Then, you don't need to include `top.Cache` in the read frame.